# Django's authentication backends change

Tags: python, django

I have to change the Django's authentication backend (the default is django.contrib.auth.AuthenticationBackend) to one of my own. The problem is that since Django stores the authentication backend for a requested user in the session, it throws errors to me when I try to use the new backend. The option is to delete all the session information. Is there a better way to do this? Or else, what is the most preferred way?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Pinax project's [account auth_backends](https://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/master/pinax/apps/account/auth_backends.py) , there it replaces with own one. I think Pinax code helps you while changing Django's authentication backend.